# Maven site include generated code folder for javadoc

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

In our project, we are generating some Java classes into `target\generated` folder.

Those classes have javadoc. When I run `mvn site` there are no apidocs generated (as expected) from these `**/target/generated/*.java` files.

Is there a way I can include them?